# Using more than 3 colors when creating Lavacharts Gauge in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-visualization, laravel-blade, laravel-6

**My Issue:**
I am not able to set more than 3 colors viz.green,yellow,red where as I want to set some more ranges in gauge with different color such as purple, blue and orange as well. I don't know where am I going wrong with the code.

**1. In Blade**

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap" id="temps_div"></div>
@gaugechart('Chart', 'temps_div')
```

**2. In controller:**

```
use Khill\Lavacharts\Lavacharts;
use Lava;

$lava = new Lavacharts; 

$temps = $lava->DataTable();

$temps->addStringColumn('Type')
        ->addNumberColumn('Value')
        ->addRow(['Chart', 11]);

Lava::GaugeChart('Chart', $temps, [
        'width'      => 200,
        'purpleFrom' => 1,
        'purpleTo'   => 15,
        'blueFrom'   => 16,
        'blueTo'     => 18.4,
        'greenFrom'  => 18.5,
        'greenTo'    => 25,
        'yellowFrom' => 26,
        'yellowTo'   => 30,
        'orangeFrom' => 31,
        'orangeTo'   => 40,
        'redFrom'    => 41,
        'redTo'      => 100,
        'majorTicks' => [
            'Low',
            'High'
    ]
]);
```

**The output which I get has no more than 3 colors:**

[image: I am not getting other colors]

Comment: the chart's [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge#configuration-options) only allows for three color ranges...

Comment: @WhiteHat So is there no other option or way where we can use more than 3 colors in the same gauge?

Comment: not unless you modify the SVG manually, when the chart's `'ready'` event fires...